# Firebase authenthication

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Im trying to use firebase for my flutter apps, and its seem there is an error in my code , i know firebaseuser need to change to user, but its seem it does not work , please help me , im new.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:quizmaker/view/signin.dart';
import 'package:quizmaker/models/user.dart';

class AuthService {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future signInEmailAndPass(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      User user = authResult.user; //the error is in this part
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide the error in your question body

Comment: Also, read the FireFlutter official documentation. It seems that you are not working with the documentation. https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code snippet:

```
  UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);
  User user = authResult.user;
```

You're trying to use an `authResult` variable that is never defined. My best guess is that you want to get the user from the `userCredential` instead, so:

```
  UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);
  User user = userCredential.user;
```

This still won't work though, since [`userCredential.user`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/UserCredential/user.html) may be null, and is thus defined as `User?` and not `User`. Since you're using `await`, you can be certain that there *is* a user, so you can do:

```
  User user = userCredential.user!;
```